# Can't open an iPhoto library because it has already been migrated

Tags: photos.app

Error text:

The content of the iPhoto library “iPhoto Library - transfer” has already been migrated to Photos.  Open Photos to view your library or use a compatible version of iPhoto to open this iPhoto library.

[image]

I can't find the Photos library that was migrated. How can I open this?

Comment: Can't you just search for the name "iPhoto Library - transfer" using Spotlight?

Comment: Photos should already know where it is. By default it will be right next to the old library, in ~/Pictures. You seem to be trying to open it in the old iPhoto, which can't open a Photos library.